# How to order by column by sequence of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query which gives me this table:

```
SELECT 
CS.Name, 
CS.FirstStep,
--CSS.NextCAPAStepID,
CS.ID
FROM CAPA_STEP_SEQUENCE CSS
LEFT JOIN CAPA_STEP CS ON CS.ID = CSS.CAPAStepID
WHERE CAPAStepID in (100000009,100000010,100000011,100000012,100000013)
GROUP BY CS.Name, CS.ID, CS.FirstStep
ORDER BY CS.FirstStep DESC
```

http://postimg.org/image/68jxjuorp/

I have to sort this table by this column from another table:

```
SELECT NextCAPAStepID
FROM CAPA_STEP_SEQUENCE 
WHERE CAPAStepID in (100000009,100000010,100000011,100000012,100000013)
```

http://postimg.org/image/ykxse0025/

When I try to order by first query by CSS.NexstCAPAStepID it makes that in the first order column NextCAPAStepID is sorted ASC and then whole table is sorted with this sequence but in my case I want to sort whole table by sequence from CSS.NextCAPAStepID. Notice also that row with value 1 in column FirstStep should be always in the top.

Final result should look like this: `http://pho.to/9XC6P`

SCRIPT FOR TABLES:

```
-- Create Table
CREATE TABLE FirstTable (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100), FirstStep INT)
-- Insert Data
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES (100000009,'Step', 1);
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES (100000010,'Step 1', 0);
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES (100000011,'Step 2', 0);
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES (100000012,'Step 3', 0);
INSERT INTO FirstTable VALUES (100000013,'Step 4', 0);
-- Create Table
CREATE TABLE SecondTable (NextCAPAStepID INT)

-- Insert Data
INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES (100000011);
INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES (100000012);
INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES (100000010);
INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES (100000013);
INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES (NULL);
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. MySQL and SQL Server are two different products..

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY CS.FirstStep DESC, CSS.NextstCAPAStepID;
If this doesn't work try giving us some test data and table definitions so I can make a fiddle out of it

Comment: Yes, i have tried and it doesn't works. I prepare test data.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions involved? You can do SELECT DISTINCT instead if you just want to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Good point! Thanks, i correct this

Comment: Show what result you expecting, please

Comment: Shouldn't your join be the other way around? If I read your data correctly, the mentioned row with *FirstStep*  is never included, since `100000009` does not exist in CAPA_STEP_SEQUENCE. (and the criterium should consequently also refer to `ID in (` instead of `CAPAStepID in (` )

Comment: I add link with expected result above.

Comment: @TeufelHalo, the link is broken!

Comment: Which link doesn't works? I check and all links works

Comment: @TeufelHalo, `http://postimg.org/image/tygo167dv/` this... You can add images to post directly..

Comment: In my case it works properly. I cannot add images directly due the lack of reputation.

Comment: @TeufelHalo, can you upload to different site? Or just paste as text in your question?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to keep the sequence of the records in which they are added in `CAPA_STEP_SEQUENCE`. However, without an extra column to do the sorting on, the order can't be guaranteed.  Doesn't CAPA_STEP_SEQUENCE have some sort of Identity() column or datetime column on which the order can be based?

Comment: That's not true. What i'm trying to do is to sort first table by sequence of second table but notice that in the beginning the second table isn't correct sorted so i can't make ROW_NUMBER() over the second table and sort with this because that's not correct sequence.

Comment: Based on what value you want sort second table. In the final result ID column sorted without any logic (100000011, 100000010, 100000012)?

Comment: Take a look at the second link with image. Assume that i make Select Distinct what gives me non duplicated records. So i have column with sequence: 100000011,100000012,100000010,100000013,NULL. So the result should look like this: http://pho.to/9XCm8

Comment: If you not using `ORDER BY`, then it is cannot be guaranteed that you get rows always in the same order. At this moment answer of @GiorgiNakeuri is your solution

Comment: BTW, are you sure your example test data is complete? Secondtable only contains a `NextCAPAStepID`. Based on your query (which joins on `CAPAStepID`) and expected data result, it seems to be missing a `CAPAStepID` column.

Answer (score 0):

It is only guess, but I think you want something like this:

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn 
             FROM dbo.SecondTable)
SELECT ft.* FROM FirstTable ft
LEFT JOIN cte c ON ft.id = c.NextCAPAStepID
ORDER BY ft.FirstStep DESC, CASE WHEN c.rn IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, c.rn
```

Output:

```
ID          Name    FirstStep
100000009   Step    1
100000011   Step 2  0
100000010   Step 1  0
100000012   Step 3  0
100000013   Step 4  0
```

I.e. order data in first table by visible order in second table, but unless you have no strict ordering it will not be guaranteed. You better add some ordering column in second table and order by that column...

Comment: From question _"Notice also that row with value 1 in column FirstStep should be always in the top"_

Comment: Notice that in the beginning the second table isn't correct sorted so i can't make ROW_NUMBER() over the second table and sort with this because that's not correct sequence.

Comment: Correct sequence of second table will be received after sorting the first table with the NextCAPAStepID but that's not case. If it's possible to sort the first table by sequence of id's from second table it will be all.

Comment: @TeufelHalo, did you try my query? Can you explain why it is not working? I can't get you...

Comment: Take a look at the second link with image. Assume that i make Select Distinct what gives me non duplicated records. So i have column with sequence: 100000011,100000012,100000010,100000013,NULL.  
Maybe this photos can explain you more:
http://pho.to/9XCgU

http://pho.to/9XCiX

Comment: @TeufelHalo, my query gives you exactly as you want here http://pho.to/9XC6P    Tell me why my query doesn't work or I am done here

Comment: Yes, it gives you exactly what you want because you have correctly sorted second table. But try to insert values of id's to second table with this sequence:  100000011,100000012,100000010,100000013,NULL. With this sequence it will be not working.

Expected result: http://pho.to/9XCm8

Comment: @TeufelHalo, ordering  100000011,100000012,100000010,100000013,NULL pho.to/9XCm8 is the same as in question ? 100000011 100000010 100000012 100000013 NULL

Comment: No, sorry a lot. It was my fault. I edited the question

Comment: @TeufelHalo, edit your questions for both those orderings. Write for this 100000011 100000010 100000012 100000013 NULL I want this. for this
100000011,100000012,100000010,100000013,NULL I want this. You have changed 5 ... times your question and picks...